# How to port postgresql time zone statement in Jpa criteria

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

newbie at JPA/Hibernate criteria, I am using Postgresql. I have to translate something like this:

```
SELECT * from mytable m where m.mytimestamptzcolum at time zone m.mytimezonecolumn < ?;
```

in a JPA criteria but after an entire day of messing with `CriteriaBuilder` and custom functions I have not found a solution. Hibernate have the nice `org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions#sqlRestriction` but I had to stay on JPA. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having read Vlad Mihalcea great [post](https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-functions-multiple-parameters-jpql-hibernate/) for the fourth time, I realize how to achieve the same result with JPA's criteriabuilder:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyTable> query = cb.createQuery(MyTable.class);
Root<MyTable> root = query.from(MyTable.class);

Predicate exp = cb.lessThan(cb.function("get_time_at_zone", Timestamp.class,
  root.get(MyTableMetamodel_.since).get(MyEmbeddedLocalDateTime_.instant),
  root.get(MyTableMetamodel_.since).get(MyEmbeddedLocalDateTime_.zoneId)),
  Timestamp.valueOf(time));
```

Above code relies on this custom function I added:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_time_at_zone(timetoconvert timestamptz, zoneid character varying) RETURNS timestamp AS
  'select $1 at time zone $2;'
language sql;
```

and I expose to hibernate by using the following class:

```
public class FunctionCastToSpecificTimezone implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

@Override
public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
    metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "get_time_at_zone",
            new StandardSQLFunction(
                    "get_time_at_zone",
                    StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP));
    }
}
```

and registered into `persistence.xml`

```
<persistence-unit name="puname">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    ...
    <properties>
        ...
        <property name="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor"
            value="my.dummy.sql.utils.FunctionCastToSpecificTimezone" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```